# How do I track how long a user has been using their iOS device per day?

Tags: ios, analytics, cllocationmanager

A few days ago an iOS app called [Moment - Track where you go](http://inthemoment.io) was released with a feature that automatically tracks how long a user uses their phone per day. How is this possible?

I noticed that it might also require location tracking to be enabled. I wonder if there is an indirect way to find out if a user is using their phone through the location APIs.

Comment: I'm not an iOS expert, but what is meant by "using" could be app dependent. 'Moment' may base it off location data, but pretend you can register for event listeners that fire on button clicks, or screen unlock, or measure time between device wake and device sleep, etc. then you could assume the user is 'using' their phone. Whether or not all this is available in the closed system that is Apple, I don't know, but only 'Moment' could really tell you how they determine what constitutes "use".